# In POSTGRESQL how to get some value from a table into variable of integer type first and then use it latter.?

Tags: postgresql

In POSTGRESQL how to get some value from a table into variable of integer type first and then use it latter.?
Actually I first want to get value in a variable of type integer and then use it in latter select query.
I know all other solution i.e. using join , using ;with clause but I not want all that. I only want what exactly I said.

Any working example will be good. I want all that working in a pgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."GetMedLastAdmnstrationDateTime"(_medicationid integer, _alfid integer)
 RETURNS TABLE("MedLastAdminDateTime" timestamp without time zone)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    declare _partitiondate timestamp = (select date from table_abc limit 1)
    Return Query
    select 
        e."MedDateTime" as "MedLastAdminDateTime"
    from public."eMAR" e
    where    
            e."AlfId" = _alfid
        and e."MedicationId" = _medicationid
        and e."MedDateTime" > _partitiondate::date
    order by e."MedDateTime" desc 
    limit 1
    ;
END
$function$
;
```

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output

Comment: `timestamp = (select date from table_abc limit 1)` <<-- a (sub-)query without ORDER BY will just yield a random row. Do you really want that? [plus: you do not need the scalar subquery, you do not even need a function]

Comment: yes I will put order y and conditions. I just given example. and I want above function working without creating any other function or any other thing

Comment: and yes I only want it with scaler subquery like above

Comment: @S-Man say like _partitiondate  is 2020-01-01 and output is 2020-06-08